# Folders as .Core and .Net in ASP.Net source project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I know ASP.Net as a beginner and I'm going to learn from an open source code project, firstly about the styles and conventions. The project I'm working on is [BlogEngine](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/).

In the source code solution there are 3 main projects listed as:

- BlogEngine.Core
- BlogEninge.Net
- BlogEngine.Tests

[image]

I don't know what is exactly the convention that has been used in this project. When I wanted to publish the website,

- I used BlogEngine.Net project and the published website works well.
- I think BlogEngine.Tests is for testing purposes (still don't know about testing procedure!)
- Could you explain to me what is BlogEngine.Core in this solution? I don't want explanation about the content of that. I don't know usual convention in splitting a project in Core Net and Tests subprojects. I found this style usual in other projects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on this particular folder structure. The CORE hosts all the common services related to data access, security, logging etc. They have done it to keep the core services clean so that they can build a new client (may be a windows app) in future without doing much rework. The .Net folder is just a  client which uses CORE services (Data, Security etc) to do operation with the database etc. This way they can ensure maximum re-usability of the CORE for other clients too. Hope this one make it clear. As for Unit testing they are using a unit testing framework called MSTEST which ships with visual studio by default.